# Editing an onClick handler function to a react element in a node module that references a function in a prop in the top level Component file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

I am using coreui CDataTable to render a table.

```
     return (
   <CDataTable
     items={data}
     fields={fields}
    ...
   />
 )
```

Everything is working smoothly. However I needed an extra button in the header of the CDataTable component that would download an excel file for the client. I noticed that CDataTable doesn't have a functionality where I can add an extra button in the header of the table, so I decided to edit the node package directly.
As far as I can tell. The component get's referenced in two files

in an index.d.ts:

```
interface CDataTable {
  ...
  loadingSlot?: ChildElement;
  loading?: boolean;
  fields?: Array<any>;
  ...
}
```

And in a CDataTable.js

```
var CDataTable = function CDataTable(props) {
  var _ref2;

  var innerRef = props.innerRef,
      overTableSlot = props.overTableSlot,
      columnHeaderSlot = props.columnHeaderSlot,
      sortingIconSlot = props.sortingIconSlot,
      ........
```

I added an extra button in the header using their `CButton` component, and I gave that button an onClick function:

```
  React.createElement(CButton, {
    className: "btn btn-primary mfe-2 excel-button",
    onClick: function onClick(e) {
      excelFunc(e)
    }
  }, "Excel indir")

  var excelFunc = function excelFunc() {
    excelButton && excelButton()
  }
```

I also added the function to the proptypes respectively:

```
excelButton = props.excelButton;
```

- 

```
  excelButton: PropTypes.func
```

and in the TS file as well

```
  excelButton?: Function;
```

The button renders correctly. However when I pass a simple function the prop:

```
...
     excelButton = {() => console.log("hi")}
```

I get an error that says excelButton is not defined. What is the issue here?

Comment: pls share minimum reproducable example

Comment: @captain-yossarian The thing is I have no idea how to share the minimum reproducable code. Since my problem depends on a node package that I downloaded. I will try to re-edit my question to include the minimum code possible...

Comment: That way you will increase your chanses to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

After trying different approaches...

- I added excelButton as a prop:

  ```
      excelButton = props.excelButton;
  ```
- And in the component proptype object as well:

  ```
  excelButton: PropTypes.func
  ```
- and then what I had to do was call `excelButton` as a function in the onClick event:

  ```
  React.createElement(CButton, {
    className: "btn btn-primary mfe-2 excel-button",
    onClick: function onClick() {
      excelButton()
    }
  }, "Excel indir")
  ```